# How to create a kernel module that can intercept all packets coming to/from a network interface

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-monitoring

I have 2 port NIC on my system - eth0 and eth1 as seen by Linux.
I want to intercept all packets coming in/to eth0, send them out through eth1 to an external device connected to the same switch as eth1 is. So I need to slap on an additional header to make it reach the correct external device.

I know that there is a concept of network taps that both the transmit and receive code in the kernel send to, but how do I create one? Also I want to capture not just IP, but all ethernet packets, I know `NETFILTER_HOOK` would have helped me get me IPv4 packets.

Comment: Have You inspected libpcap library?

Comment: Sounds a bit like you're trying to turn your Linux box into a modified hub...

Comment: Thanks, but libcap is mainly for user-space while i was looking for something in the kernel. i think i got a lead of where to look, basically register a protocol handler using dev_add_pack() which takes a struct 'packet_type' as input and 'type' of packet set to ETH_P_ALL

Answer (score 2):

The can be readily implemented with a `rx_handler`:

```
static rx_handler_result_t handle_frame(struct sk_buff **pskb)
{
    struct sk_buff *skb = *pskb;
    struct net_device *whereto_dev;

    skb = skb_share_check(skb, GFP_ATOMIC);
    if (unlikely(!skb))
        return RX_HANDLER_CONSUMED;

    *pskb = skb;

    whereto_dev = rcu_dereference(skb->dev->rx_handler_data);

    skb->dev = whereto_dev;

    return RX_HANDLER_ANOTHER; /* Do another round in receive path */
}
```

They are registered via `netdev_rx_handler_register(slave_dev, handle_frame, whereto)`. See the [bonding](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/bonding/bond_main.c) or my [uman](https://github.com/a3f/uman) driver for example usage.

`dev_add_pack` would work too, but it seems, apart from af_packet.c, all all-packet-catching users of `dev_add_pack` have been migrated to use `rx_handler`s, e.g. https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/367236/. The patch's discussion [suggests this might be more effecient](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg182746.html).

Comment: The discussion link is very helpful to me, now I understands why the HSR developer didn't use `dev_add_pack` to handle the HSR packets. Thanks.